# What does the phrase "in the sense of $\theta$ increasing" mean?

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image: SL Loney]
I've encountered this phrase many times while doing problems in dynamics. It appears when I am trying to write a vector equation using scalar quantities and almost always a derivative is involved. I don't have a clear idea on this. Some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: have you solved your doubt?

Answer (score 0):

It means that the equation hold if the **sign convention** on $\theta$ and $L$ is the same, otherwise you would have a minus sign in the equation.

It is similar to Newton's law: $$F=ma$$ where we are assuming that acceleration is positive for a positive applied force.

Comment: I had figured out the need for writing something like that I.e. to make sure both sides have the same sign. But I still don't understand how that line serves the purpose. If a positive $L$ increases $\theta$ that just means that the time-derivative of $\theta$ is positive for a positive $L$. It doesn't say anything about the second derivative.

Comment: You have to look as the equation is obtained, of course you will find the same convenction for the sign of $\theta$ and $L$. The law we are talking abuot states that the anguar acceleration is positive if L is positive, that's true also if the angualr velocity is negative.

Comment: Angular acceleration is positive if $L$ is positive - I don't understand how we got this.

Comment: It's a matter of convention. Let's consider $F=ma $ which is completely analogous for a one dimensional problem. If you set the positive direction for displacement, velocity and acceleration with the positive x-axis and also the Force in the same direction, Newton's law is F=ma. Otherwise if for F is choosen the reverse direction Newton's law is F=-ma. For the moment L and angle $\theta$ the set is the same. Every law involving vectors and direction depend upon the sign conventions adopted.